# change array value of object with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, object

i want create an array of object like this:

```
[

    'A' => { 'name':'name1', 'family':'family1'},

    'B' => { 'name':'name2', 'family':'family2'},

    'C' => { 'name':'name3', 'family':'family3'},

    'D' => { 'name':'name4', 'family':'family4'},

    'E' => { 'name':'name5', 'family':'family5'},

    'F' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

];
```

i have an array contine name and other array contine family, so i use foreach loop. but result is a Amazing. why loop in each, change all names and all family?

```
$name    = [
    'A'=>'name1',
    'B'=>'name2',
    'C'=>'name3',
    'D'=>'name4',
    'E'=>'name5',
    'F'=>'name6'
];
$family  = [
    'A'=>'family1',
    'B'=>'family2',
    'C'=>'family3',
    'D'=>'family4',
    'E'=>'family5',
    'F'=>'family6'
];
$key     = array_keys( $name );
$myArray = array_fill_keys( $key, new stdClass() );

foreach( $myArray as $k => $info ){
    $myArray[$k]->name = $name[$k];
    $myArray[$k]->family = $family[$k];
}
```

and this is a result

```
[

    'A' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

    'B' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

    'C' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

    'D' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

    'E' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

    'F' => { 'name':'name6', 'family':'family6'},

];
```

Comment: Does no one know the cause of the problem?

Comment: Interesting, you fill your `$myArray` with $key and ONE stdObject, all of the values points to one object, that why when you change 1, your whole `$myArray` change.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `foreach` loop to look something like below:

```
foreach( $myArray as $k => $info ){
    $myArray[$k] = ['name' => $name[$k] , 'family' => $family[$k]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler

```
$name    = [
    'A'=>'name1',
    'B'=>'name2',
    'C'=>'name3',
    'D'=>'name4',
    'E'=>'name5',
    'F'=>'name6'
];
$family  = [
    'A'=>'family1',
    'B'=>'family2',
    'C'=>'family3',
    'D'=>'family4',
    'E'=>'family5',
    'F'=>'family6'
];

foreach( $name as $k => $info ){
    $t = new stdClass();
    $t->name = $info;
    $t->family = $family[$k];
    $myArray[$k] = $t;
}
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [A] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name1
            [family] => family1
        )
    [B] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name2
            [family] => family2
        )
    [C] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name3
            [family] => family3
        )
    [D] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name4
            [family] => family4
        )
    [E] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name5
            [family] => family5
        )
    [F] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name6
            [family] => family6
        )
)
```

Then if you do a json_encode() on that you get what you want

```
echo json_encode($myArray);

{
    "A": {
        "name": "name1",
        "family": "family1"
    },
    "B": {
        "name": "name2",
        "family": "family2"
    },
    "C": {
        "name": "name3",
        "family": "family3"
    },
    "D": {
        "name": "name4",
        "family": "family4"
    },
    "E": {
        "name": "name5",
        "family": "family5"
    },
    "F": {
        "name": "name6",
        "family": "family6"
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE: Why you had a problem with your code

This line

```
$myArray = array_fill_keys( $key, new stdClass() );
```

is filling an array with a **reference** to a single object.

Therefore when you load data into the object in the array you are filling a single object with some data. That object is **referenced** (pointed to) in all your array occurances. So you only see data loaded in the last iteration of the loop in all the array occurances.

#### A simple test for example

```
$name    = [
'A'=>'name1',
'B'=>'name2',
'C'=>'name3',
'D'=>'name4',
'E'=>'name5',
'F'=>'name6'
];
$family  = [
    'A'=>'family1',
    'B'=>'family2',
    'C'=>'family3',
    'D'=>'family4',
    'E'=>'family5',
    'F'=>'family6'
];

$key     = array_keys( $name );
$myArray = array_fill_keys( $key, new stdClass() );

// looks like it should fill only the object in the first 'A' occurance
$myArray['A']->one = 1;
print_r($myArray);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [A] => stdClass Object ( [one] => 1 )
    [B] => stdClass Object ( [one] => 1 )
    [C] => stdClass Object ( [one] => 1 )
    [D] => stdClass Object ( [one] => 1 )
    [E] => stdClass Object ( [one] => 1 )
    [F] => stdClass Object ( [one] => 1 )
)
```

Comment: The question I asked is an example. I need to create a stdClass with the special sort in the property in my original code. So I acted like this.
$x = { prop1:null, prop2:null, ... , propN:null }
$myArray = array_fill_keys( $key, $x );
and in foreach loop set value for each property.
do you know why loop in each run cahnge all value?

Answer (score -1):

```
$myArray = [];
foreach($name as $k => $v){
    $myArray[$k] = (object)['name'=>$v, 'famili'=>$family[$k]];
}
```

Comment: While this code might  answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.